# Remove record from table when displayed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Ruby on Rails 3
I have a model with one attribute called "area_served". It consists of many records.
Example from rails console:

```
area_served: "---\n- ''\n- Ontario\n"
```

When it is displayed in my view it shows like:

```
--- - '' - Ontario
```

I Would like for it to just show the name of the places without the dashes and quotes.

I was thinking of doing a regex but am not sure how to implement the regex.

```
@dashey = /[^\w,'-]|_/
```

This is what the view file has to display it:

```
<% #current_grandstreamer.resellers.each do |reseller| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= reseller.area_served%></td>
</tr>
```

Thank you

Comment: This looks like an attribute serialized as an Array, am I right?

Comment: @MrYoshiji: It is YAML (which `serialize` uses by default) but I don't think `serialize` is being used here as it isn't an array by the time it gets to the view. AR has a bad habit of YAMLizing anything it doesn't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use gsub to substitute dashes and quotes with empty string

```
<tr>
  <td><%= reseller.area_served.gsub(/['-]/, '')%></td>
</tr>
```

You could also remove the newline character if you want

```
  area_served.gsub(/['-\n]/, '')
```

Comment: gsub seems to be the most popular. I will implement and get back.

Comment: @DDDD: Don't do this, you'll just be hiding a bigger problem with your application.

Answer (score 1):

This is a YAML:

```
"---\n- ''\n- Ontario\n"
```

In particular, it is the YAML version of this array:

```
['', 'Ontario']
```

If the `area_served` really is supposed to be a YAML'd array then you could:

```
areas_served = YAML.load(obj.area_served) # or stuff this in a model method
```

to get the array back and then render that like any other array.

However, I suspect that `area_served` is not supposed to be a YAML'd array at all, I suspect that it is supposed to be a simple string. If so, then somewhere you're trying to save an array to a text column and ActiveRecord, in its infinite wisdom, is converting the array to YAML because that's what AR does with things it doesn't understand; you're going to have to figure out where those arrays are coming from and fix that code, then you're going to have to go through your database and de-YAML the `area_served` values that have been incorrectly stored as YAML.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like YAML, indicating a serialized field. You can use the [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html#method-i-serialize) method in your model:

```
class Reseller < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :area_served
end
```

Afterwards, `area_served` is deserialized automatically:

```
reseller.area_served
#=> ["", "Ontario"]
```

Comment: This would be the right approach if it is supposed to allow multiple values, in which case `areas_served` would be a better name and hopefully the column is `text` rather than `string`

Comment: The records are from XML file